# Making procedure to insert/update qty. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to make procedure that count total slab # of from each pallet from prod_result table and insert or update that count to qty column in plt_result table that has same pallet #(plt_no)

I've tried insert, update both but doesn't work.

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE update_qty 
    is
        v_plt_no nvarchar2(20);
        v_qty number;

        cursor q1 is
        select count(slab_no) 
        into v_qty
        from prod_result 
        where plt_no = v_plt_no;

     begin

        if v_qty > 0 then
        update plt_result
        set qty = 'v_qty'
        where plt_no = v_plt_no;
        end if;
     end;
```

What am I doing wrong here? Help please.

Comment: You defined a cursor, but where are you opening it and fetching it into v_qty? As-is v_qty is NULL and any comparison against NULL result in false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which *version* you're looking for - is it the one that loops through all PLT_NOs in a table, or the one that should accept PLT_NO as a parameter. Here are both options, see whether any of them helps.

The first one uses cursor FOR loop; it is easier to maintain as Oracle does most of the *dirty* job for you (opening the cursor, fetching, exiting the loop, closing the cursor).

```
create or replace procedure update_qty
is
begin
  for cur_r in (select plt_no, count(slab_no) v_qty
                from prod_result
                group by plt_no
               )
  loop
    if cur_r.v_qty > 0 then
       update plt_result r set
         r.qty = cur_r.v_qty
         where r.plt_no = cur_r.plt_no;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

The second one accepts PLT_NO as a parameter:

```
create or replace procedure update_qty 
  (par_plt_no in prod_result.plt_no%type)
is
  v_qty number;
begin
  select count(p.slab_no)
    into v_qty
    from prod_result p
    where p.plt_no = par_plt_no;

  if v_qty > 0 then
     update plt_result r set
       r.qty = v_qty
       where r.plt_no = par_plt_no;
  end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following, where you actually open and fetch from the cursor. You'll have to assign a value to v_plt_no for the cursor to fetch anything.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE update_qty
is
        v_plt_no nvarchar2(20);
        v_qty number;

        cursor q1 is
        select count(slab_no)
        into v_qty
        from prod_result
        where plt_no = v_plt_no;

begin

   OPEN q1;
   FETCH q1 INTO v_qty;
   CLOSE q1;

   if v_qty > 0 then
      update plt_result
         set qty = 'v_qty'
       where plt_no = v_plt_no;
   end if;
end;
```